# How to delete many rows in a many to many table with one query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I want to insert many rows in a many to many table, I can use this way:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (IDTable1, IDTable2)
SELECT IDTable1, IDTable2
FROM (
VALUES
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,4),
    (4,5),
    (5,7)
) AS source(IDTable1, IDTable2)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.MyTable as TARGET
    WHERE target.IDTable1 = source.IDTable1
    AND target.IDTable2 = source.IDTable2
    );
```

Now my question is if there is some way to delete many rows with one query. For example, if I would like to delete (1,3), (4,5) and (5,7).

I guess that it would be the same but instead of using where not exists, in this way:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable (IDTable1, IDTable2)
    SELECT IDTable1, IDTable2
    FROM (
    VALUES
        (1,2),
        (1,3),
        (2,4),
        (4,5),
        (5,7)
    ) AS source(IDTable1, IDTable2)
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.MyTable as TARGET
        WHERE target.IDTable1 = source.IDTable1
        AND target.IDTable2 = source.IDTable2
        );
```

I should use where exists. But I would like to know if it is correct or not.

Comment: What is the logic by which only `(1, 3), (4, 5), and (5, 7)` get deleted?  I'm not seeing this.

Comment: Because this table has meny relationships beteween table1 and table2, and the user need to delete some specific relations, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a deletion using a JOIN:

```
delete target 
from Mytable target
inner join (
VALUES
    (1,3),
    (4,5),
    (5,7)
) AS source(IDTable1, IDTable2) on source.IDTable1 = target.IDTable1 and source.IDTable2 = target.IDTable2
```